# How to use Linq Contains()?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, contains

I am using nHibernate and I need to create a query that does this:

```
Course Table

CourseId
CourseName

Task Table // course can have many tasks

TaskName
TaskId
CousreId
```

Now I need to do a contains:

```
 session
   .Query<Course>()
   .Where(x =>
     x.Tasks.Contains(/* wants a task object. I want to do it on property level. */) &&
     x.CourseId == 1)
```

How can I change my query to do a Contains on TaskName?

Comment: var result = session.Query<Task>().Where(x => x.TaskName.Contains(taskName) && x.CourseId == 1);
    Course course;
    if (null != result) {
      // get course
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project your Tasks to a `TaskName` then use contains on that.

```
var query = session
    .Query<Course>()
    .Where(x => x.Tasks
                 .Select(t => t.TaskName)
                 .Contains(myTaskName)
             && x.CourseId == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood you can use Any method

```
session.Query<Course>().Where(x => x.Tasks.Any(t => t.Name == "task name")
                                               && x.CourseId == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var results = session.Query<Course>()
      .Where(crs => crs.Tasks.Count(tsk => tsk.TaskName == theName) > 0);
```

This should count the number of tasks with the correct name (specified in `theName` in my example), and return all courses that have a count value greater than zero, i.e. all courses that contain a task with the specific name.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to implement your own IComparer or IEqualityComparer (as I recall, I may be off) and base it on a specific property of the object.  Or use `Count()` or `Find()` instead.  Here's some pseudo code:

```
session.Query<Course>().Where(x => x.Tasks.Count(t => t.TaskProperty == "something") > 0 && x.CourseId == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
var results = session
    .Query<Course>()
    .Where(crs => crs.Tasks.Any(tsk => tsk.TaskName == theName) && crs.CourseId == 1);
```